# Can I move all the images inside a folder inside an Azure Blob to another Azure Blob?

Tags: azure, blob

Using our Power Apps we are storing pictures inside Azure Blob. Now we have finished testing the App, and we want to move the App to the live environment. So we are planning to do the following:

1. Create a live Azure Blob
2. Move or Copy (does not matter) the pictures from the Dev Blob to the Live blob.

Is this possible? and how?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not related to SharePoint!

Answer (score 0):

This is really unrelated to SharePoint, but you can use [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/features/storage-explorer/).